Rxjs: infinite loop with value in each call is the result from the previous
Says, I have an api call that take an input since which is Unix timestamp.
  fetchData = (since?) => {
    const now = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000); // Current Unix timestamp in seconds
    if (since) {
        //handle logic
        console.log(since)
    }
    return of({ since: now });
  };

Now I want to make an infinite loop that in each call, the input value to fetchData is the return value from the previous interval. I tried with this code:
fetchData().pipe(
    expand((response: any) => {
      const { since } = response;
      return fetchData(since);
    }),
    delay(3000),
    repeat(),
  );

I don't know why console.log kept giving me the same value. What have I done wrong here?

You can use interval to create the infinite loop and then switch to the inner fetchData using switchMap to get the desired result.
import './style.css';

import { interval, of, switchMap } from 'rxjs';

const fetchData = (since: any = null) => {
  const now = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000); // Current Unix timestamp in seconds
  if (since) {
    //handle logic
    console.log(since);
  }
  return of({ since: now });
};

interval(3000)
  .pipe(switchMap(() => fetchData()))
  .subscribe(console.log);

Stackblitz Demo

Tried your solution but it's not what I want to achieve. Every interval, the since parameter of fetchData should be the result of the fetchData() call in the previous interval

@manaclan pairwise will have the old and the new value grouped, so you can take the which ever you want stackblitz

I modified the fetchData a little bit and use map to solve the issue:
const fetchData = (since) => {
  const now = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000); // Current Unix timestamp in seconds
  console.log(since, now)
  return now
};

interval(3000)
    .pipe(
      startWith(Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)),
      scan((prev) => this.fetchData(prev)),
    )
    subscribe();


You can do it like this:
import { repeat, of, delay } from 'rxjs';

const someInputValue = 5;

const fetchData = (since: any = null) => {
const now = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000); // Current Unix timestamp in seconds
  if (since) {
    //handle logic
    console.log(since);
  }
  return of({ since: now });
};

const delayed = fetchData(someInputValue).pipe(delay(3000));
const repeated = delayed.pipe(repeat());

repeated.subscribe(console.log);

Stackblitz Demo

well, I checked your demo, watched the console log but the outputs aren't what I want. They should be like this:
{since: 1721700772}
{since: 1721700775}
{since: 1721700778}

